# CAPL: Sending continous message after a key stroke

Tags: can-bus, capl

I am trying to send a message continuously after a key stroke and also reset the message after a set time.

```
includes
{

}

variables
{
  int i;
  int j;
}

On key 'a'
{
  j = 1;

}

on start
{
  if(j == 1 && i <= 300)
  {
    message MyMessage msg;
    msg.signal1 = 1;
    msg.signal2 = 600;
    output(msg);
    i++;
  }
  if(i>300)
  {
    message MyMessage msg;
    msg.signal1 = 0;
    msg.signal2 = 0;
    output(msg);
    j = 0;
  }
}
```

So, on the key press 'A', it needs to keep sending the message for 3 sec, but after 3 sec is over. it needs to reset my message to 0.

I thought that "on start" is called every cyclic period. But it looks like I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`On start` will be called only once after clicking the yellow flash symbol in CANoe.
You can use a timer that can be called periodically for every 10/whatever ms you want. In `On timer` function you can have logic for your requirement.

You can use the below CAPL script as reference and modify it as per your requirement.

```
includes
{
}

variables
{  int i;
  int j;
  mstimer timer1;
}

On key 'a'
{
  j = 1;

}

On timer timer1
{
  if(j >= 1 && i <= 300)
  {
    message MyMessage msg;
    msg.signal1 = 1;
    msg.signal2 = 600;
    output(msg);
    i++;
  }
  if(i>300)
  {
    message MyMessage msg;
    msg.signal1 = 0;
    msg.signal2 = 0;
    output(msg);
    j = 0;
  }
  settimer(timer1,10);
}

on start
{
    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    settimer(timer1,10);
}
```

Comment: The lack of debugging is horrible, it is sending the signal (after some time). But resetting the signal after 3 sec to 0 is not working.

Comment: You can use write() function to use for debugging

Comment: You can use the debugger for debugging